# JNI doesn't create jclasses in a cmake-environment

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

so, i've got the problem that i've got some code which is running when compiled via terminal, but not inside a cmake-environment..

i think i could reduce my mistake to the following point:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    jclass whatever;
    std::cout << "whatever: " << whatever << std::endl; 
    JavaVM * jvm;
    JNIEnv* env = create_vm(&jvm);
    invoke_class( env );
}
```

gives "whatever: 0x7fff2fbfb820" as an output, whereas it gives "whatever: 0" as an output in a cmake-environment.

compile-flags on terminal:

```
g++ -g -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux -L/usr/bin/java -L/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/amd64/server/ CreateJVM.cpp -ljvm
```

the general code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>

JNIEnv* create_vm(JavaVM ** jvm) {
    JNIEnv* env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption options;
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";
    vm_args.options = &options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

    int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);
    if(ret < 0)
        printf("\nUnable to Launch JVM\n");
    return env;
}
void call_testing2(JNIEnv* env, jclass hClass){
    jmethodID testing2Method;
    jfloatArray floats = env->NewFloatArray(1);
    jintArray test = env->NewIntArray(1);
    jfloat *fl = env->GetFloatArrayElements(floats, NULL);
    fl[0] = 5.893241874931;
    env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(floats, fl, 0);
    jint *in = env->GetIntArrayElements(test, NULL);
    in[0] = 42;
    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(test, in, 0);
    testing2Method = env->GetMethodID(hClass, "testing2", "([F[I)I");
    int x = env->CallStaticIntMethod(hClass, testing2Method, floats, test);
}
void invoke_class(JNIEnv* env) {
    jclass helloWorldClass;
    helloWorldClass = env->FindClass("InvocationHelloWorld");
    call_testing2(env, helloWorldClass);
}
```

the same problem occurs for the jclass "helloWorldClass".
i've included the jni-path and linked the jni-libraries in the cmake-file. what is going wrong here?

Comment: maybe i should specify my problem.. the jclass "helloWorldClass" is also 0 after the line helloWorldClass = env->FindClass("InvocationHelloWorld"); - so it seems i can't create or initialize a jclass at all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jclass whatever;
std::cout << "whatever: " << whatever << std::endl;
```

A `jclass` in C++ code is a pointer to a `_jclass`, so what you print when you send `whatever` to `cout` is the value of that pointer, i.e. the address it is pointing to.

When you try to print `whatever` in your code you still haven't initialized it, and local non-static variables that are declared without an initializer will have an indeterminite value. So when printing `whatever` before you've initialized it (e.g. by assigning it the return value from a call to `FindClass`) you can end up with anything, and that "anything" just happened to be `0x7fff2fbfb820` in some cases and `0` in some cases.

Comment: maybe i should specify my problem.. the jclass "helloWorldClass" is also 0 after the line helloWorldClass = env->FindClass("InvocationHelloWorld"); - so it seems i can't create or initialize a jclass at all..

Comment: _"it seems i can't create or initialize a jclass at all"_. Sounds more like you're specifying the wrong class path for `FindClass`, or the wrong class loader is used. `FindClass` can throw an exception, which you can print with the [`ExceptionDescribe` function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp5234).